# Why doesn't my custom autoremove bash script work well?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, dependencies

I made a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is stand-in for 'sudo apt autoremove --purge'"
echo "Uninstalling ..."
apt autoremove --purge
echo "enjoy your free memory..."
```

but after turning into executable with `chmod` and running it `sudo ./script <package_name>`, the output is like this:-

```
this is stand-in for 'sudo apt autoremove-purge'
Uninstalling ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
enjoy your free memory...
```

but the same code if i run with usual command:-
`sudo apt autoremove --purge <package_name>`, then it works as follows:-

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386* libaudio2:i386* libcdparanoia0:i386* libdbusmenu-qt2:i386* libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386* libgstreamer1.0-0:i386*
  libmng2:i386* libmysqlclient20:i386* libopus0:i386* libqt4-dbus:i386* libqt4-declarative:i386* libqt4-network:i386* libqt4-opengl:i386* libqt4-script:i386*
  libqt4-sql:i386* libqt4-sql-mysql:i386* libqt4-xml:i386* libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386* libqtcore4:i386* libqtdbus4:i386* libqtgui4:i386* libqtwebkit4:i386*
  libtheora0:i386* libvisual-0.4-0:i386* libxss1:i386* libxv1:i386* qt-at-spi:i386* skype* skype-bin:i386* sni-qt:i386*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 30 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 133 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

What am I missing in my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently ignoring the arguments you pass to the script.

It has to look like

```
#!/bin/bash
apt autoremove --purge "$@"
```

The `"$@"` evaluates to all the arguments passed to your script in Bash, so if you call it like

```
sudo uninstall-this-shit sudoku cowsay sl
```

it will expand to `sudoku cowsay sl`.

Comment: There's usually no reason to use `$*`, `"$@"` is almost always the better choice.

Comment: @muru care to explain why that is? I'm curious.

Comment: @muru Thanks, of course you're right. I keep confusing those two...

Comment: @grooveplex See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF - basically `$*` gives you all arguments as one item whereas `$@` gives you all arguments as single items.

Comment: @grooveplex try this script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24738014/ (preferably in a folder with some files)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the argument inside

```
apt autoremove --purge $1
```

> Thanks for  @muru and @Byte Commander notes!
>
> In order to use all parameters `$@` should be used instead of `$1`
>
> `apt autoremove --purge $@`

Comment: Note that this will only use the first shell argument. If you run the script as e.g. `sudo uninstall-this-shit sudoku cowsay sl`, it will only uninstall `sudoku` but ignore `cowsay` and `sl`

Comment: @ByteCommander - thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer (+1 for your answer)

Comment: As muru correctly pointed out in his comment below my answer, it's better to use `"$@"` here instead of `$*`.

Comment: @ByteCommander - thanks again for your comments!